# Replace a string to multiple string with regex in sql

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I'm trying Replace function in Oracle, I can't find any regex for my desired result.

```
SELECT REPLACE('Cat,Dog',',','') FROM DUAL;
```

desired result:
E.g : `'Cat,Dog'` result is `'Cat','Dog'`

Comment: You want your split result int rows or in columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT regexp_replace('Cat,Dog','([^,]+)', '''\1''') FROM DUAL;
```

Result:

```
'Cat','Dog'

SELECT regexp_replace('Cat,Dog,Lion','([^,]+)', '''\1''') as res
FROM DUAL;
```

Result:

```
'Cat','Dog','Lion'
```

An no, using \0 without a capture group will not work in ORACLE regex

```
SELECT regexp_replace('Cat,Dog,Lion','[^,]+', '''\0''') as res
FROM DUAL;
```

Result:

```
'\0','\0','\0'
```

Comment: Please attach some explanation why this would work and preferrable some regex101 demo :)

Comment: You can even remove capturing group i think to make it even faster (and cleaner, as pattern will be shorter): [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CDXnob/1)

Comment: PCRE2 regex is not guaranteed to work in ORACLE rexexp, use dbfiddle for SQL demo, not reg101.

Comment: Ok, thanks for explanation :) But anyway, this way or another, you got it right :)

Answer (score 0):

You do not need regular expressions and can just replace `,` with `','` and then add leading and trailing single quotes:

```sql
SELECT '''' || REPLACE('Cat,Dog',',',''',''') || '''' AS list_string
FROM   DUAL;
```

Which outputs:

| LIST_STRING |
| --- |
| 'Cat','Dog' |

*Note: This would translate a `NULL` input to `''`. If you are using this to build a dynamic list for an `IN` expression then `''` is the same as `NULL` so no erroneous transformations will have occurred.*

---

However, if you are trying to use this in an `IN` expression then you do not need to transform the string and can just use a sub-string match (including the surrounding delimiters):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   animals
WHERE  ',' || 'Cat,Dog' || ',' LIKE '%,' || name || ',%';
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Animals (id, name) AS
SELECT 1, 'Cat' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Dog' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Rat' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Cat |
| 2 | Dog |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Voi2j6uL)